# Run Automator script when new files are added

Tags: macos, applescript, photos, automator, dropbox

I'm trying to make an automator script to import photos in Photos.app that are in my DropBox folder.

Nothing spectacular you'd say - true. But I can't get it to work. On a change in the folder, the script checks **all** files in the specific dropbox folder, and wants to import all of them. So photos is asking for 'duplicates'. Yes, I can turn this warning message off, but I don't want to have all my photos in duplicate.

How should I design my automator script to import the photos in photos, whenever a new picture is added into the dropbox folder?

Beside that, two other questions:

1. Will the script always work when set as folder action?
2. How to make sure that automator only works with the files that are new? (Uploaded in the last hour i.e. won't work, sometimes Dropbox uploads 20 new pictures in less than a minute)

OS X El Capitan (10.11.4)

Comment: I've the same problem with an automator folder action for my downloads folder. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Haven't found one sadly enough :(